# In Angular JS, how do I inject data from directive attribute to template?

Tags: javascript, templates, angularjs

Here's my directive:

```
app.directive("helloWorld", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      name: "bind"
    },
    template: "<div>a {{name}} a</div>"
  };
});
```

Here's how I use it:

```
<hello-world name="John Smith"></hello-world>
```

I expect this page to be like this, when I run it:

```
<hello-world>
  <div>a John Smith a</div>
</hello-world>
```

But for some reason, `name` is not injected and actual result is like this:

```
<hello-world>
  <div>a {{name}} a</div>
</hello-world>
```

Anything I'm missing? I'm using Angular JS 1.0.2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The scope declaration is strange. I'm not sure about the `"bind"` declaration - maybe its something from the previous versions.

The current syntax for binding to a directive's attribute is like this:

```
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      name: "@name"
    },
    template: "<div>a {{name}} a</div>"
};
```

In general, `@attributeName`. See here for [more information on directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: Just answered my own question and then it appeared that there's already an answer :-) https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/tfArd7DuFxs

Comment: I would suggest adding some more information about scope. "@name" binds to the given property in parent scope; "=getName()" binds to the value of the Angular expression 'getName()' in parent scope; and "&doStuff()" bind a function to the scope which execute the given angular expression when called.